# Finding cycle using pregel

Tags: scala, graph, cycle, spark-graphx

The task is to find cycles of certain size k, where k is an user input, using Scala pregel. However, I am lost on what to do on what messages should be sent in pregel when a cycle has being found. What I have tried so far is using a string which contains list of vertices that it has passed through and put that into the vertex attribute. Then a cycle is detected if the srcAttr already contains the dstId. But I am not sure what to do after to get the total number of cycles. Also, the task also states it is not a cycle if it contains other smaller cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Each vertex sends messages to its neighbors containing (1) the source vertex id, and (2) the number of hops that the message is traversing (initially set to 1).

Each vertex re-routes the received messages after incrementing (2) value by one.

Check each message whether the msg.src_vid == msg.dst_id, and see the number of hops